# unable to modify global variable in c

Tags: c, linked-list, global-variables

I'm learning C, and in this program I'm trying to implement a simple linked list. 
Each node of the list contains an integer, and a pointer to the next node.
Pointer `head` points to the first node in the list, but initially the list is empty, so I initialized `head = NULL`.

I want to do two operations on the list - populate it, and print it.

To populate the list, I'm calling function `insert_node` with two arguments: `head`, and the integer I want to insert.

The problem is I need the function `insert_node` to change the value of `head` (so it points to the updated list, instead of NULL). I'm not sure how to do that, so I made `head` a global variable, and I'm trying to change its value. 
For some reason, even though the value of `head` is changed inside the function `insert_node`, when I call the function again, head still has value of NULL.

Questions:

1. Why is global variable value is not changed globally?
2. I'm aware that using global variables is not a good practice, so how can I properly update the pointer to the list?
   I was thinking about having `insert_node` function actually return a pointer to the list, is this a good way?

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<stdlib.h>
>
>
> struct node {
>
>   int data;
>   struct node *link;
> };
>
> void insert_node(struct node *head, int n); 
> void print_list(struct node *head);
>
> struct node *head = NULL;
>
> main() {
>
>   int i;
>
>   for(i=1; i<5; i++) 
>
>       insert_node(head, i*i);
>
>   print_list(head);
>
> }
>
> void print_list(struct node *head) {
>
>   if(head == NULL) 
>
>       return;
>
>   else {
>
>       printf("%i ", head->data);  
>       print_list(head->link);
>   }
>
>   return;
> }
>
>
> void insert_node(struct node *head, int n) {
>
>   struct node N = {n, NULL};
>   struct node *next, *prev;
>   int prev_data = 0;
>
>   //case one: list is empty - point head to N, and set N.link to NULL
>
>   if(head == NULL) 
>
>       head = &N;
>
>   //case two: n is less than first element in the list:
>
>   else if(n < head->data) {
>
>       N.link = head;
>       head = &N;
>   }
>
>
>   else {
>
>       next = head;
>
>   //case three: N.data is equal to existing element, do nothing:
>
>       while(next != NULL) {
>
>           if(n == next->data) {
>
>               printf("this element already exists.\n\n");
>               return; 
>           }
>           prev = next;          //save the current element
>           next = next->link;    //look at the next element
>       }
>
>   //case four: N.data is greater than last element:
>
>       if(n > prev->data) {
>
>           prev->link = &N;
>           return;
>       }
>
>   //case five: N.data is in between list elements:
>
>       next = head;
>
>       while(next != NULL) {
>
>           prev_data = next->data;   //save the current element
>           prev = next;              //save pointer to current element
>           next = next->link;        //look at the next element
>
>           if((n > prev_data) && (n < next->data)) {
>
>               prev->link = &N;
>               N.link = next;
>               return;
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
>   return;
>
> }
> ```

Comment: If you use GCC, compile with `-Wshadow` as well as your other warning options (`-Wall` at minimum).  It will let you know that the `head` parameters to the functions mean that those functions cannot access the global variable `head` (the local variable hides the global one).  (In C++, there's a scoping operator to disambiguate (`head` vs `::head`), but not in C.)

Comment: you are passing the `head pointer` to the `insert` function per value, while it should be passed by reference. You should use `insert_node ( struct node ** head)`;

Comment: Independently of the changes in the way that `head` is handled, you need to dynamically allocate memory for the new nodes (`malloc()` and error check). At the moment, you store the data in a local variable and then add the address of that local variable to the list.  This is not a recipe for happiness.  Your cases 3, 4, 5 should be handled more simply.  Since you're maintaining the list in sorted order, you need to stop scanning when the next pointer is null or the data in the next node is greater than or equal to the node you're about to add.  You should not rescan the list from the start.

Comment: Jonathan, you were correct about the "recipe for (un)happiness". After fixing the shadow variable name, I kept getting only the last element into the list. I spent a couple of hours debugging - it turned out that the local variable `N` is created at the same address every time the `insert_node` function was called. Since `head` points to `N`, this means that `head` will always point to the latest `N`.  Is this issue the reason to use malloc?

Comment: Jonathan, I really appreciate your comments. I will look into improving cases 3-5. A couple more questions: What error checking should be done? Regarding gcc options - what are there any other good options to use (for a beginner like me)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Because you pass global `head` **by value** to function `insert_node()`.
   Then function `insert_node()` makes local variable (which, by the way, also has the name `head` which might confuse you, because it's local and not global). Modifies that local `head` and those changes are not visible in global variable `head`. It's so called shadowing (variable with the same name but within local scope is distinct from any other variable with the same name).
2. Pass address of head to function and make function parameter pointer to pointer to structure.

**Declaration**

```
void insert_node(struct node **ptr_to_head, int n);
```

**Usage**

```
insert_node(&head, 5);
```

Now you can modify head by dereferencing `ptr_to_head` in your `insert_node` function:

```
(*ptr_to_head)=&new_node;
     ^            ^
     |            |
   head       =  value returned by malloc
```

And yes, you can return `head` from insert_node function, but don't forget to make an assignment to `head` in main function.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, I said that the insert code should not need as many cases as you have.  Here's the proof.  It includes code to free the allocated list.  Notice that there are fewer special cases (just three: duplicate entry, insert at head, insert somewhere else).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

void insert_node(struct node **head, int n);
void print_list(struct node *head);
void free_list(struct node **phead);
void test_insert(struct node **head, int n);

int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    free_list(&head);

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        test_insert(&head, i*i);
    test_insert(&head, 0);
    test_insert(&head, 7);
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        test_insert(&head, i*i - 3);
    test_insert(&head, 7);
    test_insert(&head, 0);

    free_list(&head);
    return 0;
}

void insert_node(struct node **phead, int n)
{
    struct node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate node for %d\n", n);
        exit(1);
    }

    node->data = n;

    struct node *head = *phead;
    struct node *next = head;
    struct node *prev = NULL;

    while (next != NULL && n > next->data)
    {
        prev = next;
        next = next->link;
    }

    if (next != NULL && n == next->data)
        free(node);
    else
    {
        node->link = next;
        if (prev == NULL)
            *phead = node;
        else
            prev->link = node;
    }
}

void test_insert(struct node **head, int n)
{
    printf("%2d:", n);
    insert_node(head, n);
    print_list(*head);
}

void print_list(struct node *head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %2i", head->data);
        head = head->link;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void free_list(struct node **phead)
{
    struct node *head = *phead;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        struct node *next = head->link;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
    *phead = 0;
}
```

Example output:

The value to the left of the colon is the value 'inserted'; the value to the right is the resulting list.

```
 1:  1
 4:  1  4
 9:  1  4  9
16:  1  4  9 16
 0:  0  1  4  9 16
 7:  0  1  4  7  9 16
-2: -2  0  1  4  7  9 16
 1: -2  0  1  4  7  9 16
 6: -2  0  1  4  6  7  9 16
13: -2  0  1  4  6  7  9 13 16
22: -2  0  1  4  6  7  9 13 16 22
 7: -2  0  1  4  6  7  9 13 16 22
 0: -2  0  1  4  6  7  9 13 16 22
```

Answer (score 1):

You added a global variable named head but you forgot to remove the parameters on the functions insert_node, print_list, etc. that has the same name.  The local takes precedence over the global, so your assignments are assigning to the local not the global.

Remove the parameters with the same name and the issue will go away.

I'm not condoning the usage of globals though :)